# What t2 equipment can the new alpha clones use?

Tags: eve-online

I'm a little confused as to what alpha clones are limited to in regards to ship equipment. What equipment can they use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha Clones can not use any T2 ships. They can use the T2 modules they have skills for. These are some mid and low slot modules such as small shield boosters and armor repairers, and damage mods like gyrostabilizers.

If you want to determine if you can use a specific module or ship, just check the required skills tab in the item's info and crosscheck it with [the list of trainable skills on alpha clones](https://community.eveonline.com/news/dev-blogs/introducing-clone-states-and-the-future-of-access-to-eve-online/).

You can also check what the skill enables at each level from the skill's info.

A relevant quote from the developer blog is included below.

> To begin with, we are planning that the Alpha skill set will be focused on using tech one Frigates, Destroyers and Cruisers. Alpha clones will only be able to use ship and weapon skills native to their faction.

Answer (score 1):

ELECTRONIC WARFARE

- Warp Disruptor II
- Warp Scrambler II

ELECTRONICS & SENSOR UPGRADES

- Auto Targeting System II
- Co-Processor II
- Passive Targeter II

ENGINEERING EQUIPMENT

- Micro Capacitor Booster II
- Small Capacitor Booster II
- Small Energy Neutralizer II
- Small Nosferatu II
- Small Cap Battery II
- Medium Cap Battery II
- Large Cap Battery II
- Capacitor Flux Coil II
- Capacitor Power Relay II
- Cap Recharcher II
- Power Diagnostic System II

HARVEST EQUIPMENT

- Miner II
- Mining Laser Upgrade II
- Ice Harvester Upgrade II

HULL & ARMOR

- Small Armor Repairer II
- Medium Armor Repairer II
- Expanded Cargohold II
- Nanofiber Internal Structure II
- Reinforced Bulkheads II
- Small Remote Armor Repairer II
- Adaptive Nano Plating II
- EM Plating II
- Thermal Plating II
- Kinetic Plating II
- Explosive Plating II
- Layered Plating II
- 100mm Steel Plates II
- 200mm Steel Plates II
- Damage Control II
- Small Hull Repairer II
- Medium Hull Repairer II

PROPULSION

- 5MN Microwarpdrive II
- Inertial Stabilizers II
- Overdrive Injector System II

SCANNING EQUIPMENT

- Cargo Scanner II
- Ship Scanner II
- Survey Scanner II

SHIELD

- Small Shield Booster II
- Medium Shield Booster II
- Large Shield Booster II
- Small Shield Extender II
- Medium Shield Extender II
- Large Shield Extender II
- EM Ward Amplifier II
- Thermal Dissipation Amplifier II
- Kinetic Deflection Amplifier II
- Explosive Deflection Amplifier II
- Small Remote Shield Booster II
- Shield Flux Coil II
- Shield Power Relay II
- Shield Recharger II

SHIP MODIFICATIONS

- ALL

SMARTBOMBS

- Micro EMP Smartbomb II
- Micro Plasma Smartbomb II
- Micro Graviton Smartbomb II
- Micro Proton Smartbomb II

TURRETS & BAYS

- Ballistic Control System II
- Gyrostabilizer II
- Heat Sink II
- Magnetic Field Stabilizer II
- Tracking Enhancer II
- Tracking Computer II

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eve/comments/5cwztg/alpha_clone_t2_modules_per_skills/)